# Android - delete a row from sqlite

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sqlite, delete-row

i amm working on an app to develop my knowledge so far i have created a calendar app which user can make appointment when clicking on a date. i then have a delete button which opens all the appointments created in a fresh activity, there i have: a list view which displays all appointments a textview which displays the selected appointment (selected by the user to delete) and a button remove. i want this button to remove the selected appointment (row) from the database. so far i have manged to write to the database and display the information but i can not seem to get it to delete the row i want..

this is how i populate the textview with the selected appointment (row) from the listview

```
//populate textview with selected item from sqlite data
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        selection.setText(stg1[position]);
        delBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

this is my actionlistener for my remove button what would i need to put here to delete that selected row ( i have tried many ways but my app just crashes

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.removeBtn:

        break;
    }

}
```

hope im being clear enough.. any help would be much appreciated many thanks

Comment: Write a delete query (same like how you did select query). Remaining flow stays same.

Comment: I don't see any SQL in your code.  Write a DELETE query.

Comment: ok will give it a try thank u for ur help both of u

Comment: where would i place the delete query?

Comment: It'll help you.. http://www.androidtipsbynama.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-sqlite-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if you want to delete a row from the SQLite table or from the listview.

If you want to delete a row from the listview, simply remove the item from the array and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

If you want to delete the row from the SQLite DB then you need to write a `DELETE` query: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Comment: yh i need to understand the delete query.. thank u for ur reply

Comment: where would i place the delete query?

Comment: probably in the `onClick` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
db.delete("UsersTable", usernameString +"="+usernameString+ " AND " +this.userId+"="+userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the SQLiteDatabase class you can always do something like this:

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/yourpackage/databases/dbname.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
db.execSQL("delete from your_table where your_column = '" + some_value + "'");
db.close();
```

I don't know the extent of your code, but based on what you've provided us I would say drop that chunk into your onClick()

Then like slayton had said, use the notifyDatasetChanged() to update your list.  Otherwise it will delete from the database, but you'll never know it until you relaunch the query that populated the list.

Also you may want to make a global variable that says what list item is currently selected.  That way you can set it in your onListItemClick() and then just quickly remove it based on what you previously selected in your onClick instead of having to mess around with that switch-statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.
In your database handler class, add

```
  int id=1;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+" = "+id+";");
  db.close();
```